# Error al recibir datos

Tags: flutter, dart

hola a todos no tengo mucho tiempo en esto. tengo esta funcion que se ejecuta al hacer ontap en un boton

```
onPressed: () {
Fluttertoast.showToast(
msg:
"Solicitud enviada con exito",
toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
backgroundColor: Colors.red,
textColor: Colors.white,
fontSize: 16.0);
//print(mensaje);
_loadRequest();

 _loadRequest() async {
 final respuesta = await _CorrecionCertificates.getRequest();
  }
```

respuesta es una lista que declare de forma global

```
class _CertificateCorrectionState extends State<CertificateCorrection> {
  List<Data>respuesta = [];
```

siempre obtengo este error en consola E/flutter ( 8663):

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

y probe con tecnicas de debugging y la ocasionante del problema es esta

```
final respuesta = await _CorrecionCertificates.getRequest();
```

aca les dejo el controlador

```
class ControllerCorrecionCertificates {
  //instancia del servicio
  CorreccionService _correccionService = CorreccionService();

  Future <SaveRequestModel>getRequest() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      const token =
        "tokenjfjjf";
     prefs.setString('x-token', token);
    final String? xtoken = prefs.getString('x-token');
    //print(xtoken);

    if(xtoken != null || xtoken != ""){
       final datos = await _correccionService.fetchRequest(xtoken!);
       return datos;
       
    }else{
      throw Exception('Failed to load Request progress');
    }
  }
}
```

porfavor llevo dias estancado en este problema. les agradeceria mucho su respuesta. gracias

Comment: El error se encuentra al momento de parsear tus datos que viene de tu API, puedes mostrar un resultado por postman el tipo de dato que devuelve tu API?

Comment: @EdHuamani hola amigo. te refieres a esta respuesta? {
    "status": 200,
    "msg": "Solicitud registrada con Exito!",
    "data": {
        "id": 12,
        "idCurso": "2",
        "idUsuario": "1",
        "descripcion": "descripcion 2",
        "estado": 1,
        "estadoSolicitud": 0,
        "createdAt": "2023-10-09T19:36:08.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-10-09T19:36:08.836Z"
    }
}

Comment: Sorry por la respuesta tardía, pero en tu respuesta de api data es un json(Map), al parecer esperas un array(List) al consumir el servicio, por eso te marca error al intentar parsear